# Cassandra get OS type using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is it possible to get the OS Cassandra is installed on using CQL?

For example in PostgreSQL you can run the query `select version();` which will return:

`PostgreSQL 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit`

Essentially, it returns the version of PostgreSQL and the OS type installed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to do this in Cassandra through CQL.

It isn't particularly relevant since some deployments are serverless like [K8ssandra.io](https://dtsx.io/3znMa05) where Cassandra is deployed in Kubernetes.

There are also some architectures where the coordinators are [Stargate.io](https://dtsx.io/2XHbiRo) nodes which are not Cassandra nodes in the cluster. [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) is an example of this where it's serverless and truly cloud-native. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cassandra 4.0?  If so, you should be able to query the `os.name` key from the `system_views.system_properties` table:

```
> SELECT * FROm system_properties WHERE name='os.name';

 name    | value
---------+----------
 os.name | Mac OS X

(1 rows)
```

Although, as Erick pointed out the info isn't terribly useful.  You could be running in an Alpine Linux container on an Ubuntu host, but Cassandra would only have visibility to Alpine.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I would need it to run on Cassandra 3.x as well as 4.0.